# An example of a compact multiplicatively unbounded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, compactness, topological-groups

My teacher asked me to build an associative topological Hausdorff compact ring $R$ with $1$, which is multiplicatively unbounded. That means there is a neighborhood $U\ni 1$ such that $FU\not=R$ for each finite subset $F$ of $R$.

I am somewhat stuck, because I have a small stock of topological rings, and I see only two main ways to build such an example: to endow a compact topological group with a multiplication  or to endow a ring with a compact ring topology. Both of these ways require a concordance of many conditions and therefore it seems to me that my success of the construction “depends on luck, but not on method”.

Comment: Hi: Could I ask a question about the definition of multiplicatively unbounded? As written, it looks like it is of the form $\exists U\forall F(FU\neq R)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: I would have expected an "unbounded" condition to be of the form $\forall\dots\exists\dots$... but in any case thanks for verifying :)

Comment: Is it always possible to compactify a topological ring into a compact topological ring? And then maybe unboundedness would be inherited by the compactification? This is what I'd hope for if I already had a multiplicatively unbounded ring.

Comment: A form $\forall\dots \exists\dots$  has the “bounded” condition, and the “unbounded” condition is its negation. But an approach defining boundness with different orders of the quantors is also good – just now we are writing a paper on the relations of different types of boundness in topological groups. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, even a Hausdorff abelian topological group $G$ (in our case, the additive group of the ring) can be compactified  into a compact topological group iff $G$ is totally bounded. That is, if for each neighborhood  $U$ of $0$ there is a finite subset $U$ of $G$ such that $U+F=G$.

Comment: Shoudn't such a ring be a topological feild?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the question answered I note that a required example was given by Uri Bader [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228869/kind-of-multiplicative-total-boundedness-in-hausdorff-compact-rings).

Comment: Okay, +0 for keeping the site clean.